# submit instagram app review gets Oops, an error occurred

Tags: instagram

The second I submit my app for review. I get into a screen blank screen saying "Oops, an error occurred." no further information.
I selected "My app allows people to login with Instagram and share their own content." from the radio buttons. fill in the form. click on submit and get to this error !

Might be related to the new API change and/or the fact they remove the permissions field.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error on Instagram. they fixed it now.